# For example the file could be ABC_1234 or DEF_3344 or EFG_4456. the input table to be PROD."ABCproduction". or PROD."DEFproduction"

Tags: python, excel, filenames

I receive excel files that come in with all different file names but the first 3 charters will always tell me the production table I need to send the data. For example the file could be ABC_1234 or DEF_3344 or EFG_4456. I need then the imput table to be PROD."ABCproduction". or PROD."DEFproduction" or PROD.EFGproduction"

Comment: You could start with CELL("filename",A1) and then use left(CELL("filename",A1),3)...

Comment: Thanks for your help. My solution was set  grp= (file_nm[:3])                                                                        
                                                                                   
                                                                               
    PROD."'+grp+'ProductionX"   Thanks